# Defining incomplete struct of specialized class

Tags: c++, specialization, incomplete-type

I'm having problems declaring an incomplete struct inside a class specialization and later defining it.

```
struct Foo {
    template <bool Y, typename D>
    struct Bar {};

    template <typename D>
    struct Bar<true, D> {
        struct Qux;
    };

    template <typename D>
    struct Bar<true, D>::Qux { int x; };
};
```

This code works in gcc, but fails in clang 3.3:

```
r.cpp:42:26: error: non-friend class member 'Qux' cannot have a qualified name
    struct Bar<true, D>::Qux { int x; };
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

If the code is written in namespace scope (without `struct Foo`), it works in clang too.

On the other hand, if `struct Foo` is turned into a template, as follows, the code breaks in gcc-4.9 (unreleased), though it keeps working in gcc-4.7.

```
template <typename X>
struct Foo {
    template <bool Y, typename D>
    struct Bar {};

    template <typename D>
    struct Bar<true, D> {
        struct Qux;
    };

    template <typename D>
    struct Bar<true, D>::Qux { int x; };
};
```

Clang fails with:

```
r.cpp:43:26: error: template specialization or definition requires a template parameter list corresponding to the nested type 'Bar<true, type-parameter-1-0>'
    struct Bar<true, D>::Qux { int x; };
                         ^
r.cpp:43:26: error: non-friend class member 'Qux' cannot have a qualified name
    struct Bar<true, D>::Qux { int x; };
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
```

Gcc-4.9 fails with a similar error:

```
r.cpp:43:26: error: too few template-parameter-lists
     struct Bar<true, D>::Qux { int x; };
                          ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't have a choice but to put that definition in namespace scope (or inside `Bar`). Paragraph 9/1 (n3337) says your code is illegal:

> **If a *class-head-name* contains a *nested-name-speciﬁer***, the *class-speciﬁer* shall refer to a class that was
>   previously declared directly in the class or namespace to which the *nested-name-speciﬁer* refers, or in an
>   element of the inline namespace set (7.3.1) of that namespace (i.e., not merely inherited or introduced by
>   a *using-declaration*), and **the *class-speciﬁer* shall appear in a namespace enclosing the previous declaration.**
>   In such cases, the *nested-name-speciﬁer* of the *class-head-name* of the deﬁnition shall not begin with a
>   *decltype-speciﬁer*.

Answer (score -3):

```
struct Foo {
  template <bool Y, typename D>
  struct Bar {};
};

template <typename D>
struct Foo::Bar<true, D> {
  struct Qux;
};

template <typename D>
struct Foo::Bar<true, D>::Qux {
  int x;
};
```